# Which API to change Google group auto-message settings?

Tags: python, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-client

I'm trying to change the auto-response messages for a google group in my company's google account via one of their API's (these messages need to be turned on and off automatically).

I've used the [group settings api](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/groupssettings/v1) to change other settings on the group, but the message settings (among many others) don't appear to be part of that [API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/groupssettings/v1/python/latest/groupssettings_v1.groups.html).

Is there another API for changing group settings?

Comment: You may try with the email settings API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_vacation-responder_settings) but probably in vain.

Comment: I noticed several people have voted to close this question as off-topic.  I'd be interested to know why.  To me, this appears to be "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", given that it's asking about a specific programming API and (hopefully) has a specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API setting to modify Groups auto-responder. It must be changed via the web UI.

Answer (score 1):

I find this today. --I've not try-- I've try and this not work for me for a group email.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/vacation_settings

I try something like

```
aemail = "group email"
adescription = "something else"
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'p--cut--2.json', scopes)
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated(aemail)
http_auth = delegated_credentials.authorize(Http())

service = build('gmail','v1', http=http_auth)

vacation_settings = {
    'enableAutoReply': True,
    'responseBodyHtml': adescription,
    'restrictToDomain': restrictToDomain,
}

result = service.users().settings()\
        .updateVacation(userId='me', body=vacation_settings).execute()

pprint.pprint(result)
```